# Conversion to_string provides NULL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, string, formula

I've been trying to convert a decimal row into a string row using a few methods. Below is my CSV file:

[image: CSV]

also, note that csv header has been updated too,

```
State;AverageRainfall;ProbabilityBelow;ProbabilityNormal;ProbabilityAbove
```

And white space was removed from the headers removed. (including the blank cells)

First method using to string:

[image: To string]

The second method using quotes:

[image]

Tried the same with integers, a similar result was depicted:

[image: Integer to string]

[image]

Removing the file name from the column doesn't help:

[image]

Using QGIS 3.6.3-Noosa. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MBain File name is blacked out

Comment: Try to use items in 'Fields and Values' menu on the right hand of the text editor. There are listed all fields in the current layer. Maybe your field names are somehow mangled...

Comment: Did you try: to_string("AverageRainfall")  ?  You need the expression to_string("ColumnName") with the column name between quotation marks.